# Should the brushes be this bright on my vacuum cleaner's motor?

Tags: electrical, appliances

I have a vacuum cleaner that sometimes slows down while in use. If I turn it off and turn it back on again it usually solves the problem.

I took the debris chamber and the filter off, so I can see the vacuum cleaner motor running directly beneath a plastic screen. The arcs coming from the brushes of the motor are extremely bright. Is this normal or does this indicate a problem with the motor?

[image]

Comment: Can you check the condition of the brushes and commutator? and that the bearings run freely?

Comment: There is lots of stuff on the internet about maintenance of large DC motors and they talk a lot about commutators since that's the primary maintenance point. I'd read up on that so you know what normal looks like on a commutator, then maybe have a closer look.  The unit looks too new to have a brush used up, but that'll chew up a comm lickety split.   Also disassembling the motor and changing the orientation of the brushes will cause a need to "wear in" again.  Many small motors have only 2 brushes, so if a brush is struggling, so's the motor.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No, this is not normal. Some small arcing around the brushes is normal. In this case the rotor had segments that shorted resulting in very high current on the brushes for a percentage of the rotation. The higher current resulted in the larger arcs from the brushes since they take longer to extinguish.

Not long after taking this photograph the motor began to smoke and smell horribly. So I disposed of it.

Answer (score 0):

Yes. Arcs are bright no matter how small. The presence of arcs doesn't dictate the state of the vacuum. They may change if something is wrong and sometimes brushes do go bad, but I would look elsewhere first. 
Belts are a common issue. Does the motor stop/become affected if you step on the front of the vacuum during operation?

Comment: The size of the arc is import! Two large and the brush and comm are being damaged. I maintain a few 50HP DC motors that have dual shunt split brushes (big ones in layman's terms) the proper arcs are very fine and evenly destributed across the entire brush. If the brush is badly worn it can cause excessive arcing usually because the brush has exceeded its life and is running on the copper conductor or spring. A poorly built comm can eat a brush in a very short time but even these can be repaired.